# how to create bootable USB drive (ubuntu)

Tags: boot, usb, drive

I want to create a bootable USB key drive in order to be able to run/install an Ubuntu ISO image with it.

How can I do that using Ubuntu (command line) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `GNU dd`:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sd<X> && sync
```

where `<X>` is your drive letter.

Comment: Could you explain me the meaning of the option "bs=4M", please ? (your command is tested by my friend and it works)

Comment: From `man dd`:
`bs=BYTES
    read and write BYTES bytes at a time`
So every single quantum of time, 4 megabytes are written to pendrive.